# Power sets and functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $a\colon\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to\mathbb N$ be the function defined by $a(X)$ equals $0$ if $X$ has infinitely many elements and $a(X)$ equals the number of elements in $X$ if $X$ has finitely many elements.

1. What is $a(\{x : x \in\mathbb N\text{ and }x\text{ is odd}\})$
2. Is it a one to one function? Explain
3. What is the range?

I understood that so far:
 1. My answer is 1 just by reading in the text as there are infinitely many elements that can be plugged in
 2. unsure about this one 
 3. would this be $(0,\infty)$

Comment: Also, for $N$ do you mean the set of natural numbers?  (else, it doesn't make sense to talk about "odd" $x$ for an arbitrary set $N$).

Comment: yep N as the set of natural numbers so $x>0$

Comment: What's $c$ in the first one? Is it $a$?

Comment: ah yep my bad a typo that one

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct: the set of odd natural numbers is infinite., so $a(\{x:x\in \mathbb{N},\: x \:\:\text{odd}\})=0$.
2. A one to one function can only send a single element to any output. In this case, is it true that there is only one subset $A\subset \mathbb N$, such that $a(A) =0$?
3. Since this function only ever spits out an integer, what is a more appropriate way of writing the range?

Comment: would it be something like $(0-> infinity, x\in Z$)

Comment: I think that you have the correct idea. The notation would be something like $\{x: x\in \mathbb Z, \:\: x\geq )\} = \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$. There are many ways to write it, but the point is that each nonnegative integer is in the range.

Comment: @Ashan: Since your natural numbers include $0,$ the range should be $\Bbb N.$ It's relatively straightforward to prove, too. Given $n\in\Bbb N,$ let $$A_n=\{m\in\Bbb N:m<n\}.$$ You should be able to show by induction that $A_n$ has cardinality $n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N.$

Comment: Also, is $c$ a cardinality function? If so, then your answer to number 1 should be $\aleph_0.$

Comment: sorry cameron that was an $a$ not a $c$

WSL thanks for you answers, I would like to say for your second statement the answer is no there is more than one value of A that would give 0. There by making this NOT a one to one function. Would that be correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about 1. The set is infinite, therefore it is mapped to $0$.

For 2 you need to determine whether different sets are mapped to different numbers. For example, if the set in (1) is mapped to $0$, are there any other sets that are mapped to $0$? If the answer is positive, then this is not one to one.

For 3, it would be better to consider this as a subset of $\Bbb N$, rather than an interval. What sort of numbers can be obtained by $a$? Can you find a set $A$ such that $a(A)=5$? What if we replace $5$ by some other $n$? What does that mean?

Comment: As my understanding goes there is more than one value of a(X) that gives us 0 as such it is not a one to one function. For the 3rd question I think I get the idea but I am unsure how to write it with the right notations

Comment: It's not a matter of notation. It's a matter of clarity. What idea did you get from my answer?